# SQL Server : separating data from one column into two based on other column data

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2012 and want to create a view that does the following:

My table has:

```
MovType | Qty
In      | 200
Out     | 10
```

Now I want to create a view that basically goes through the whole table and depending on if the `MovType` is `In` or `Out` assigns to a special dynamic column.

So basically I need:

```
InQty | OutQty
200   | 0
  0   | 10
```

I know this can be done with `CASE`, but not sure of the code. Secondly speed is an important factor, so is there any particular way to do this with least overhead possible?

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `CASE`, it should be efficient. The case statement does not need to read from disk like a `JOIN`, it's a very simply command that is unlikely to cause performance issues.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MovType='In' THEN Qty Else 0 End AS InQty,
       CASE WHEN MovType='Out' THEN Qty Else 0 End AS OutQty
FROM dbo.Table1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d507f/3/0